# Why does MKTileOverlayPath contain these values?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mapkit

Using MapKit, I am trying to render custom tiles. I am using Xamarin Forms with C# (not Swift).

I have followed the tutorial found here; https://www.raywenderlich.com/9697133-advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-mapkit-tiles

I have overridden the URLForTilePath method so I can change the default path returned for each tile.

I have a database of tiles using zoom, x, y. These tiles are in the format of Google Maps tile system (zoom is between 1-19). Knowing MapKit uses a slightly different structure to this I have converted the database into the following file structure:

- ./zoom/x/y.jpg

It is my intention to use the zoom, x, and y values, to create a file path to each tile image. Something like this (`string tileName = $"{path.Z}/{path.X}/{path.Y}.jpg";`)

My problem is that the X, Y, Z values passed through the MKTileOverlayPath object do not match with the values I would have expected. As an example, here are typical values I see when using the map (Note- if I was doing this test on Google maps, the zoom would roughly equate to 19-20).

[image]

In case the image does not work; X: 4307763200, Y: 40, Z: 6213412560.

From researching I have found Z is supposed to be the zoom level. I am unsure how a X of 4x10^9 and a Y of 40 could be in the same range.

I do not know what to do with these values, or what these values represent. Please may anyone inform me how to get these values to Google's tile format or similar.

Comment: according to the MS docs, ContentScaleFactor should be 1 or 2.  Since it's not, that makes me wonder if the other data is bad too

Comment: It seems like it. Do you have any idea what could be causing the bad data? My theory is that it is a compiler issue as I am using Visual Studio on windows instead of mac. I am also facing other problems using windows.

Comment: The actual build is done on the Mac - I doubt its a compiler issue.  If you can create a small sample that reproduces the error, I would file an issue on the Xamarin iOS Github.

Comment: Most servers use a default tile size of512*512, apple uses a default of 256*256. give `self.tileSize = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)` a try.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Back dating to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 fixed it. Filed a bug report at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15247